# Como puedo crear el campo horario con tipo de dato time que solo sea entre las 8 y 20hs?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

```
create table Agenda (
IdAgenda numeric unique,
dia varchar (20),
hora time 


);
```

Como puedo poner para que el horario solo pueda ser entre las 08:00 y 20:00 horas.

Answer (score 1):

Según tu pregunta entiendo lo siguiente ... si no es así dímelo y lo vemos.

Añado que eso creo que no lo puedes hacer en la definición de la tabla, en el código que compartes sólo estás declarando los tipos, lo de definir los horarios tendrás que gestionarlo en la lógica de tu app uses PL-SQL, Java, PHP , etc ... pero te recomiendo que el campo día no sea varchar, si no timestamp, el cual guarda un long con el tiempo exacto que reservas, este número te da desde el año hasta el milisegundo y en la lógica de tu app controlas si el tiempo está entre el horario que quieres.

Por ejemmplo, la tabla quedaría así:

```
create table Agenda (
IdAgenda numeric unique,
reserva TIMESTAMP 
);
```

Si lo necesitas comparte tu código de la app y vemos lo de las restricciones horarias.

Saludos!

Comment: y como lo implemento a mi codigo?

Comment: Sería bueno una explicación del uso de `time_format()` sino parece mas un  comentario que una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

A partir de MySQL 8.0.16 puedes agregar una restrición CHECK ([CHECK Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)) al crear la tabla.

Las restricciones CHECK se evalúan para las declaraciones INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, LOAD DATA y LOAD XML y se produce un error si una restricción se evalúa como FALSE.

```
CREATE TABLE Agenda (
IdAgenda numeric unique,
dia varchar (20),
hora time CONSTRAINT Agenda_hora_check CHECK (hora BETWEEN '08:00' AND '20:00'));

-- ó

CREATE TABLE Agenda (
IdAgenda numeric unique,
dia varchar (20),
hora time,
CONSTRAINT Agenda_hora_check CHECK (hora BETWEEN '08:00' AND '20:00'));
```

Este INSERT se ejecuta correctamente:

```
INSERT INTO Agenda VALUES (1, 'viernes', '12:00');
```

Este INSERT falla (mensaje de error: "Check constraint 'Agenda_hora_check' is violated"):

```
INSERT INTO Agenda VALUES (2, 'viernes', '20:10');
```

Comment: A partir de MySQL 8.0.16 para ser exactos.

Answer (score 0):

Para MySQL >5.5 puedes usar un disparador que arroje un error:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ag_bi BEFORE INSERT ON Agenda
FOR EACH ROW
   IF NEW.hora not between '08:00' and '20:00' THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
         SET message_text = 'Hora inválida';
   END IF
//
```

Y probablemente necesitarás crear otro igual para `BEFORE UPDATE`.